# How can I write a line equation with two equal signs into a simpler format?

Tags: linear-algebra

So the question I'm trying to solve goes like this:

Given the line $r : \{2x + y + z - 1 = y + 2z = 0\}$,
find equations for the plane through $r$ and passing through the point $A = (2, 1, 0)$.

So I can solve this if I turn this into a cartesian or a parametric equation. But since there are two equal signs in this line, I'm stumped.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: So that means you have two algebraic expressions *both* equal to $0$. Why are you stumped?

Comment: Hint: planes that pass through line $r$ are of the form $\,a(2x + y + z - 1) + b(y + 2z) = 0\,$.

Comment: The line r is the intersection of the plane $2x+y+z-1=0$ and the plane $y+2x=0$. That is all the notation for r means

Comment: Oh. I should've known that. Thank you for your help!

Comment: @leo if you have figured out a solution (based on the comments) then you should post it as an answer.